# Textbook recommendation for practical simulation of quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations

I'm hoping to find a textbook (or other type of reference) which discusses an introduction to simulating quantum systems with classical computers. To clarify, I'm interested in finding a resource that goes through the more fundamental matrix mechanics/manipulations, and various tips and tricks on a practical level, aimed at younger graduate students already familiar with quantum theory, but not its practical implementation. My interest is mainly in systems of spins/qubits.

To be clear, I am not looking for a tutorial on any particular quantum computing package, but rather a more broad introduction to "do-it-yourself". For instance, there is the following reference (https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7050) I found which is similar to what I was thinking, though specifically for Mathematica - something like this, but more broad/less language specific would be ideal.

Any suggestions are greatly appeciated!

Comment: Most physicists are "familiar" with one language (rarely more than two), so I would be surprised if there were any texts (likely on any subject) written language agnostic (or pseudo-code, whichever you prefer).

Comment: I don't know of any book / tutorial type reference. But there are notes floating around from Anders Sandvik on exact numerical simulations and Frank Pollmann on tensor-network methods. You can also use Qiskit and TenPy and Circ and various packages for quantum simulations. Usually you work with someone and they give you some starter code and then you go from there. **I don't recommend Mathematica for most quantum stuff.** Python is great, Julia is also great for tensor networks. You can also look at iTensor.

Comment: Anyway, for exact simulations (or using Krylov sectors), you really just code up the Hamiltonian as a (sparse) array and then evolve in time. If $H$ is time dependent, you can use python with the solve_ivp function to integrate numerically (C++ is also good for this). For time independent, you can use expm_multiply, or diagonalize and find eigenstates whose evolution is easy. For tensor network stuff check out TenPy and iTensor.